# dispatch_queue and Thread and task order

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

guys，little confused abt dispatch queue and thread,
there could be several queues and they dispatch tasks to different thread,
if the queue is serial, tasks executed in a line and may be in different, its not a problem.
but if we have 2 serial queues，can we manage order of them ?

if we put some Database operations in these 2 queues, the data may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If these two queues serve different functional purposes that merit having separate queues, that's fine, but you'd probably just set up a third queue for database interaction, to which those two would dispatch their database interactions. Let this third queue, a dedicate low-level database queue, coordinate all interaction with the database.

If these two queues are just two random database interaction queues, then one might argue for refactoring the code to consolidate them into one.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can manage the order. But not with `dispatch_queue`. You have to use `NSOperationQueue`:

```
NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSBlockOperation * operation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // do something
    }];
[queue addOperation:operation1];

NSBlockOperation * operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do something
}];

[operation2 addDependency:operation1];
[queue addOperation:operation2];
```

In this code `operation2` will start only when `operation1` did complete.

Comment: well, this is a method, but how abt 2 queues ?

Comment: What is the reason to put two blocks which depend on each other to different queues?))

Comment: @nickyu Alexander's point was, I suspect, the academic observation that with operation queues, unlike dispatch queues, you can establish dependencies between operations on separate queues. With operation queues, you can, for example, make operation 2 on queue X dependent upon the completion of operation 1 on queue Y. This doesn't seem to be terribly helpful in your scenario (because presumably you don't want queue Y to have to be explicitly aware of every operation queue X submits, nor vice versa), but it is a feature of operation queues.